# unicode-math's \symit in superscripts and subscripts

Tags: unicode-math

I have a separate font for Unicode's mathematical symbols block which I use with `unicode-math`. It has a different font for the italic lambda, and I can access it using `\symit{λ}`. However this doesn't seem to work in script size, ie. in superscripts and subscripts.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{InfiariaMath.otf}[range={"1D400-"1D7FF}]

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        &αβγδεζηθικλ \\
        &\symit{αβγδεζηθικλ}\\
        &{}^{\symit{αβγδεζηθικλ}}\\
        &{}_{\symit{αβγδεζηθικλ}}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Fonts]

This doesn't seem to happen with other fonts like Cambria Math. Any ideas?

Comment: The issue depends on specific features of the particular proprietary font

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The OpenType font generated had additional glyphs for smaller optical sizes which were used instead. Generating them again without these fixed the issue.